# Difference between Spanning set and Postitive Spanning Set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

I do understand the difference as mentioned in the texts about spanning set and positive spanning set, im somehow missing how if $v_1.. v_r$ is a positive spanning set for $R^n$, then $v_2 ... v_r$ spans entire $R^n$, can someone explain this trivial questions. And what is the physical reason why we need spanning set other than the fact that there always exists a vector in the descent slope.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what is a *positive* spanning set?

Comment: Postive spanning set is a set of vectors whos positive span is $R^n$. Postive span of of a set of vectors $[v_1,.. v_r]$ in $R^n$ is the convex cone formed by all the positive linear combinations of $v_1,...v_r$. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=\sum a_iv_i$ with $a_i\gt0$. Let $-v=\sum b_iv_i$ with $b_i\gt0$. Then $$(a_1+b_1)v=\sum b_1a_iv_i-\sum a_1b_iv_i=\sum_2(b_1a_i-a_1b_i)v_i$$ and $a_1+b_1\ne0$, so $$v=\sum_2{b_1a_i-a_1b_i\over a_1+b_1}v_i$$

Comment: if it wouldnt be too much of a hassle, could you just tell what is the physical significance for the conceptualisation of a positive spanning set? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I never came across the concept of a positive spanning set before I saw your question, and I have nothing to say about its physical significance.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ is a positive spanning set for the whole space, one can in particular write $-v_1$ as a linear combination of those vectors with *positive* coefficients. Choose such an expression and let $c_1\geq0$ be the coefficient of $v_1$ in it. Now subtracting $c_1v_1$ from both sides of the equation, the left hand side is $-(1+c_1)v_1$ and the right hand side has become a linear combination of only $v_2,\ldots,v_n$. Since $1+c_1\geq1$ we can divide by $-(1+c_1)$, and obtain an expression that shows that $v_1$ is in the span of the other vectors. So that span must already be the whole space.

Comment: wouldnt that mean that the coefficients on the rhs are no more positive, cause we are dividing by -(1+$c_1$)? Am i missing something here? or do we just divide by ((1+$c_1$)) and say that $-v_1$ can be written as a linear combination from $v_2...v_n$?

Comment: When as I indicated you express $v_1$ as linear combination of the other vectors, then coefficients will definitely be negative (though some may be zero). That is why one cannot expect those vectors to be a _positive_ spanning set. However, what is shown here is that without the "positive" requirement, they _do_ form a spanning set.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i think i got your argument now, as i mentioned in the previous comment, could you comment on the significance of postive spanning set?

Comment: Your book would be a better place to find out about the importance of positive spanning set than I could tell you. It might have to with decomposing the space as a union of cones, but I am not particularly knowledgeable about this.